# Suppress warnings when using a python chunk inside an Rmd file

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, reticulate

I am trying to hide some python warnings when knitting an Rmd file. The usual chunk setup "warning=F, message=F" doesn't seem to work for python chunks.

Example of Rmd file with a python chunk that, purposefully, generates warnings:

````
---
title: "**warnings test**"
output: pdf_document
---


```{python, echo=F, warning=F, message=F}
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'col2': [0, 0, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df[df.col1==1]['col2']=2
```
````

Comment: Add `import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')`

Comment: yup. that works, thanks! wanna answer the question so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')` to the python chunk:

````
```{python, echo=F, warning=F, message=F}
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'col2': [0, 0, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df[df.col1==1]['col2']=2
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to suppress warnings in Python itself, take a look at official Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings) on this.